# DataTable Filtering with ajax server side dont work

Tags: javascript, ajax, filter, datatables

I'm populating my table from server-side, and I want to implement a filter to a column.

I have created a dropdown-menu that calls my javascript class, but is not filtering, is always showing all the records.

So my objective, is select one of the options in the dropdown and when click filter the table.

```
 $(".company_link").on("click", function (e) {
    companies_type = $(this).data('value');
    $("#company_text").html(companies_type);
    clients_types_table.ajax.reload();
});

clients_types_table = $('.clients_types_table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    columns: [
        {data: 'id', width: '5%', searchable: true,}, //0
        {data: 'origin_id',searchable: true}, //1
        {data: 'description',searchable: true}, //1
        {data: 'company_id', width: 80, searchable: true}, //6
        {data: 'id', width: 80, searchable: true, orderable: true}, //6
    ],
    language:{
        processing:""
    },
    ajax: {
        url: AjaxURL,
        data: function (d) {               
            d.action = "admin_clients_types";              
            d.option = "list";
            d.company_id = companies_type;  // I want to filter this column

        }
    },
    rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
        var buttons = "<div class='center btn-group btn-group-sm'>";
        buttons += "<button type='button' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-ownerid='" + data.company_id + "' data-type='edit' title='Edit' data-placement='top' class='btn btn-sm bg-blue gridbutton'><i class='far fa-edit fa-fw' ></i></button>";
        buttons += "<button type='button' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-type='delete' title='Delete' data-placement='top' class='btn btn-sm bg-red gridbutton'><i class='fas fa-trash fa-fw fa-sm'></i></button>";
        buttons += "</div>";
        $('td:eq(-1)', row).html(buttons);
        $('td:eq(-1)', row).find('button').tooltip();
    }
});
```

This is my table code

```
<div class="header">
                <h2>
                    MyClients Types
                    <button type="button" id="comp_button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span id="company_text">AllanTeste</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php $tbo = new TBAS(); $comps = $tbo->getCompaniesList(); foreach ($comps as $k=>$v){ ?>
                            <li><a id="<?=$v['value']?>" data-value="<?=$v['value']?>" class="company_link"><?=$v['name']?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </h2>
                <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5 m-t--5 m-b--5">
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" id="create_clients_type" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                            <span>Create MyClients Type</span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover clients_types_table dataTable">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Origin ID</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Company ID</th>
                                    <th>Tools</th>                                                                   
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my function to go in database.

```
public function getCompaniesList() {
    $companies_type = $this->dbm->from(TBLM_COMPANIES)->get()->result();
    $data=[];
    foreach ($companies_type as $k=>$v){
        $d = [
            'name'=>$companies_type[$k]['name'],
            'value'=>$companies_type[$k]['id']
        ];
        array_push($data,$d);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you written any server-side code, which is accepting `company_id` param and then doing db query?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the following code in server-side to do the query in db

 public function getCompaniesList() {
        $companies_type = $this->dbm->from(TBLM_COMPANIES)->get()->result();
        $data=[];
        foreach ($companies_type as $k=>$v){
            $d = [
                'name'=>$companies_type[$k]['name'],
                'value'=>$companies_type[$k]['id']
            ];
            array_push($data,$d);
        }
        return $data;
    }

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't see use of `company_id` param anywhere in the code. Please post your full server-side code also in the question.

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal ok! I Edited my question, so you can see the function that goes in database.

Comment: There are no many things you have to do in your server-side. I don't think you are even able to populate the table. Because some parameters are needed by the datatable in response to work. Please go over [this doc](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), it tells what are the least parameters needed by datatable to process response. Then you may come back, if you find any difficulty